# Notify onbackpressed() from which fragment was called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity and I add a ListFragment. When I click a button a new Fragment replaces the ListFragment. I use addTobackStack(null) so When I press the back button I will end to the ListFragment. If the user doesn't presses the back but instead clicks on a button then he goes to another one new Fragment. From there I want the user to go back to ListFragment, so I dont use addTobackStack() when I make the fragmentTransaction.

The schema is :

```
ListFragment -------> GameFragment --------> EndFragment
```

from `GameFragment` I can go back to `ListFragment` and from `EndFragment` I have to go to `ListFragment` and not `GameFragment`.

So I'm guessing I have somehow to override the onBackPressed() in my Activity so when I'm on the `EndFragment` to make a transaction to the `ListFragment`

The problem is I don't know how to reference to the `EndFragment` when I override `onBackPressed()`

(Unless there is a better way to perform this action...)

onBackPressed() code I use right now :

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        Log.i("FINISH", "Finish");
        finish();
    } else {
        Log.i("FINISH", "POP STACK");
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is to remove your `AF` activity from the BackStack, which is what holds all of the previous activities and where the back button looks to find the previous activity.

For this, in your `AF` activity, add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag to your intent, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BF.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

The other option is to override what happens when you press the back button. Override the `onBackPressed()` method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   super.onBackPressed();
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, BF.class);
   goToMainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
   startActivity(goToMainActivity);
 }
```

Comment: They are not activities. They are fragments. Sorry for the misunderstanding my post has caused, I made some edits so it can be more understandable what I ask.